# How to set Tab activity in android Tab Example api13

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment2 .java class

```
  public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

    ..

        }

    }
```

fragemnt1.java

```
public class MyListFragment1 extends ListFragment {

String[] month = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, month);
    setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I have to set Tab Activity in fragment to a fragent.xml file I have. Please tell me how I can do this because am not able to. I have tried much onlist item click of fragment1. I want to display tab activity in fragment 2 in any item click

Answer (score 0):

The use of `TabActivity` is now discouraged. Please use the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) widget along with `Fragments`. Using the compatibility library you'll get support for old versions of Android.

Links you'll need to make it work:

- The [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) widget
- An [adapter for the pager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)
- A [short intro to the widget](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) on the official android dev blog
- A [library to get indicators with your pager](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Of course, you'll get lots of tutorials about that using your favorite search engine.

Comment: can u please share some Link related this  please

Comment: am doing first time related this exam please help me

Comment: hope http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/ helps you